# PHP: Read existing xml file and write new content

Tags: php, xml

I have a .xsd-file and of course I can create a .xml-file from it. So basically I have a blank .xml-file (with no data/text)

With PHP I want to read the blank .xml-file, interate the nodes and fill them depending on the tag with data from the database.

There seem to be many options: XMLReader, XMLWriter, DOMDocument, SimpleXML
I don't know where to start. What would be the easies/leanest way?

More Information:
[Here you kann find the .xsd-file...](http://www.xml-oncobox.de/DownloadData/Dokumente/eb_darm-F3.1.1_pr%C3%BCfschema%20xml%20(140920).zip)
The following .xml-file I created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Patienten>
<InfoXML>
    <DatumXML></DatumXML>
    <NameTudokusys></NameTudokusys>
    <VersionTudokusys></VersionTudokusys>
</InfoXML>
<Patient>
    <Stammdaten>
        <PatientID></PatientID>
        <GeburtsJahr></GeburtsJahr>
        <GeburtsMonat></GeburtsMonat>
        <GeburtsTag></GeburtsTag>
        <Geschlecht></Geschlecht>
        <EinwilligungTumordoku></EinwilligungTumordoku>
        <EinwilligungExterneStelle></EinwilligungExterneStelle>
    </Stammdaten>
    <Fall>
        <Anamnese>
            <RelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen></RelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen>
            <JahrRelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen></JahrRelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen>
            <NichtRelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen></NichtRelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen>
            <JahrNichtRelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen></JahrNichtRelevanteKrebsvorerkrankungen>
            <DKGPatientenfragebogen></DKGPatientenfragebogen>
            <PositiveFamilienanamnese></PositiveFamilienanamnese>
        </Anamnese>
        <Grundgesamtheiten></Grundgesamtheiten>
        <Fallinfos>
            <Zentrumsfall></Zentrumsfall>
            <Organ></Organ>
            <RegNr></RegNr>
            <HauptNebenStandort></HauptNebenStandort>
            <FallNummer></FallNummer>
            <EingabeFalldaten></EingabeFalldaten>
        </Fallinfos>
        <Diagnose>
            <DatumErstdiagnosePrimaertumor></DatumErstdiagnosePrimaertumor>
            <DatumHistologischeSicherung></DatumHistologischeSicherung>
            <ICDOHistologieDiagnose></ICDOHistologieDiagnose>
            <Tumorauspraegung></Tumorauspraegung>
            <ICDOLokalisation></ICDOLokalisation>
            <KolonRektum></KolonRektum>
            <TumorlokalisationRektum></TumorlokalisationRektum>
            <praeT></praeT>
            <praeN></praeN>
            <praeM></praeM>
            <UICCStadium></UICCStadium>
            <SynchroneBehandlungKolorektalerPrimaertumoren></SynchroneBehandlungKolorektalerPrimaertumoren>
            <MRTBecken></MRTBecken>
            <CTBecken></CTBecken>
            <AbstandFaszie></AbstandFaszie>
        </Diagnose>
        <PraetherapeutischeTumorkonferenz>
            <VorstellungPraetherapeutischeTumorkonferenz></VorstellungPraetherapeutischeTumorkonferenz>
            <EmpfehlungPraetherapeutischeTumorkonferenz></EmpfehlungPraetherapeutischeTumorkonferenz>
        </PraetherapeutischeTumorkonferenz>
        <EndoskopischePrimaertherapie>
            <DatumTherapeutischeKoloskopie></DatumTherapeutischeKoloskopie>
            <OPSCodeEndoskopischePrimaertherapie></OPSCodeEndoskopischePrimaertherapie>
        </EndoskopischePrimaertherapie>
        <ChirurgischePrimaertherapie>
            <ASAKlassifikation></ASAKlassifikation>
            <DatumOperativeTumorentfernung></DatumOperativeTumorentfernung>
            <OPSCodesChirurgischePrimaertherapie></OPSCodesChirurgischePrimaertherapie>
            <NotfallOderElektiveingriff></NotfallOderElektiveingriff>
            <Erstoperateur></Erstoperateur>
            <Zweitoperateur></Zweitoperateur>
            <AnastomoseDurchgefuehrt></AnastomoseDurchgefuehrt>
            <TMEDurchgefuehrt></TMEDurchgefuehrt>
            <PostoperativeWundinfektion></PostoperativeWundinfektion>
            <DatumPostoperativeWundinfektion></DatumPostoperativeWundinfektion>
            <AufgetretenAnastomoseninsuffizienz></AufgetretenAnastomoseninsuffizienz>
            <AnastomoseninsuffizienzInterventionspflichtig></AnastomoseninsuffizienzInterventionspflichtig>
            <DatumInterventionspflichtigeAnastomoseninsuffizienz></DatumInterventionspflichtigeAnastomoseninsuffizienz>
            <Revisionseingriff></Revisionseingriff>
            <DatumRevisionseingriff></DatumRevisionseingriff>
            <OPmitStoma></OPmitStoma>
            <Stomaangezeichnet></Stomaangezeichnet>
        </ChirurgischePrimaertherapie>
        <PostoperativeHistologieStaging>
            <pT></pT>
            <pN></pN>
            <postM></postM>
            <Grading></Grading>
            <ICDOHistologiePostoperative></ICDOHistologiePostoperative>
            <PSRLokalNachAllenOPs></PSRLokalNachAllenOPs>
            <PSRGesamtNachPrimaertherapie></PSRGesamtNachPrimaertherapie>
            <GueteDerMesorektumresektion></GueteDerMesorektumresektion>
            <AnzahlDerUntersuchtenLymphknoten></AnzahlDerUntersuchtenLymphknoten>
            <AbstandAboralerTumorrand></AbstandAboralerTumorrand>
            <AbstandZirkumferentiellerTumorrand></AbstandZirkumferentiellerTumorrand>
        </PostoperativeHistologieStaging>
        <PostoperativeTumorkonferenz>
            <VorstellungPostoperativeTumorkonferenz></VorstellungPostoperativeTumorkonferenz>
            <EmpfehlungPostoperativeTumorkonferenz></EmpfehlungPostoperativeTumorkonferenz>
        </PostoperativeTumorkonferenz>
        <Lebermetastasen>
            <LebermetastasenVorhanden></LebermetastasenVorhanden>
            <LebermetastasenAusschliesslich></LebermetastasenAusschliesslich>
            <PrimaereLebermetastasenresektion></PrimaereLebermetastasenresektion>
            <BedingungenSenkundaereLebermetastasenresektion></BedingungenSenkundaereLebermetastasenresektion>
            <SekundaereLebermetastasenresektion></SekundaereLebermetastasenresektion>
        </Lebermetastasen>
        <PraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <EmpfehlungPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></EmpfehlungPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <DatumEmpfehlungPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></DatumEmpfehlungPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <TherapiezeitpunktPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></TherapiezeitpunktPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <TherapieintentionPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></TherapieintentionPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <DatumBeginnPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></DatumBeginnPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <DatumEndePraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></DatumEndePraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <GrundDerBeendigungDerPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie></GrundDerBeendigungDerPraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
        </PraeoperativeStrahlentherapie>
        <PostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <EmpfehlungPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></EmpfehlungPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <DatumEmpfehlungPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></DatumEmpfehlungPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <TherapiezeitpunktPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></TherapiezeitpunktPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <TherapieintentionPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></TherapieintentionPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <DatumBeginnPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></DatumBeginnPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <DatumEndePostoperativeStrahlentherapie></DatumEndePostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
            <GrundDerBeendigungDerPostoperativeStrahlentherapie></GrundDerBeendigungDerPostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
        </PostoperativeStrahlentherapie>
        <PraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <EmpfehlungPraeoperativeChemotherapie></EmpfehlungPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <DatumEmpfehlungPraeoperativeChemotherapie></DatumEmpfehlungPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <TherapiezeitpunktPraeoperativeChemotherapie></TherapiezeitpunktPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <TherapieintentionPraeoperativeChemotherapie></TherapieintentionPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPraeoperativeChemotherapie></GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <DatumBeginnPraeoperativeChemotherapie></DatumBeginnPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <DatumEndePraeoperativeChemotherapie></DatumEndePraeoperativeChemotherapie>
            <GrundDerBeendigungDerPraeoperativeChemotherapie></GrundDerBeendigungDerPraeoperativeChemotherapie>
        </PraeoperativeChemotherapie>
        <PostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <EmpfehlungPostoperativeChemotherapie></EmpfehlungPostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <DatumEmpfehlungPostoperativeChemotherapie></DatumEmpfehlungPostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <TherapiezeitpunktPostoperativeChemotherapie></TherapiezeitpunktPostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <TherapieintentionPostoperativeChemotherapie></TherapieintentionPostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPostoperativeChemotherapie></GruendeFuerNichtdurchfuehrungPostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <DatumBeginnPostoperativeChemotherapie></DatumBeginnPostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <DatumEndePostoperativeChemotherapie></DatumEndePostoperativeChemotherapie>
            <GrundDerBeendigungDerPostoperativeChemotherapie></GrundDerBeendigungDerPostoperativeChemotherapie>
        </PostoperativeChemotherapie>
        <BestSupportiveCare></BestSupportiveCare>
        <Prozess>
            <DatumStudie></DatumStudie>
            <Studientyp></Studientyp>
            <PsychoonkologischeBetreuung></PsychoonkologischeBetreuung>
            <BeratungSozialdienst></BeratungSozialdienst>
            <GenetischeBeratungEmpfohlen></GenetischeBeratungEmpfohlen>
            <GenetischeBeratungErhalten></GenetischeBeratungErhalten>
            <ImmunhistochemischeUntersuchungAufMSI></ImmunhistochemischeUntersuchungAufMSI>
        </Prozess>
        <FollowUp>
            <DatumFollowUp></DatumFollowUp>
            <LokoregionaeresRezidiv></LokoregionaeresRezidiv>
            <LymphknotenRezidiv></LymphknotenRezidiv>
            <Fernmetastasen></Fernmetastasen>
            <Zweittumor></Zweittumor>
            <Verstorben></Verstorben>
            <QuelleFollowUp></QuelleFollowUp>
        </FollowUp>
    </Fall>
</Patient>
```

First, I have to navigate to certain nodes (for example "DatumXML") and enter a value.
Second,  I have to iterate all subnodes of certain nodes (for example Stammdaten) and enter values.

Comment: I provided more information by editing my question. How do I get away the "hold status"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [SimpleXMLIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php) is going to be your best bet. You didn't quite explain the structure of your XML, but you should be able to do something like:

```
$iterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);
for ($iterator->rewind(); $iterator->valid(); $iterator->next()) {
    $node = $iterator->key();

    // Get data from database based on node name
    $iterator->{$node} = $data;
}

$finished_xml = $iterator->asXML();
```

If you're structure is more complex, you should be able to adapt this to what you need. Just remember that a SimpleXMLIterator is a SimpleXMLElement and you can use the same methods and techniques.

Comment: Thank you very much for your anser. I added some detailed information.